# How to round decimals on MongoDB without using Decimal128 type

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, decimal, mongoose-schema

I have a question about the decimal support. I want to work with decimals and I know Mongo suggests to use [Decimal128](https://www.mongodb.com/developer/products/mongodb/bson-data-types-decimal128/) type. It solves the rounding format on db but on the other hand I need to write decimal(BSON) to number converter getters while getting data.

I want to use decimals without changing data type. I use mongoose’s $inc, $dec operators a lot with bulk operations. If I continue to use Number(on mongoose, Double on Mongo) type, I can see very long decimals end of the some operations. For example, if I $inc 2.4 with 1.2 result will be 3.5999999999999996 (floating point numbers problem).

Is there a way to say Mongo to round selected fields’ final values’ to max 2 via mongoose model or directly on db somehow? Setters don’t work because there is no problem with 2.4 or 1.2, the problem is the result of the inc operation. Or post hooks don’t work with bulks.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to change to use `Decimal` on Mongo.  If it stays as `Double` you will always be at peril of having some calculation, explicit or internal, get tripped up on floatingpoint conversion.

Answer (score 0):

you can use $round in mongo.

refer this
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/round/

Comment: Actually, I'm looking for a central solution without updating existing queries. Because I have complex and non aggregation queries. Maybe there is a way to say from the mongoose collection for specific field or from Mongo directly to round final value. Because Decimal128 type does this when it is specified at model but as I stated type also changes as BSON. I want to keep still Number and final value as rounded. Thus I don't prefer to write any converter or formatter getter if there is a way.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue with [change streamers](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/change-streams.html). I check the post data after the any insert or update operation on specific collection. If there is a value that match with my long digit decimal pattern, updating with rounded version.

```js
const FORMAT_NEEDED_DECIMAL_REGEX = /^\d+\.\d{3,}$/;
const DECIMAL_ROUNDING_PLACE = 2;

const config = [[{
  $match: { operationType: { $in: ['insert', 'update'] } },
}], {
  fullDocument: 'updateLookup',
}];

const yourModelStream = YourModel.watch(...config);

yourModelStream.on('change', (postData) => {
  const { documentKey: { _id: id }, updateDescription, operationType, fullDocument } = postData;

  const document = operationType === 'update' ? updateDescription.updatedFields : fullDocument;

  const updateQuery = Object.keys(document).reduce((acc, field) => {
    if (FORMAT_NEEDED_DECIMAL_REGEX.test(document[field])) {
      return { ...acc, [field]: { $round: [`$${field}`, DECIMAL_ROUNDING_PLACE] } };
    }
    return acc;
  }, {});

  if (Object.keys(updateQuery).length) {
    YourModel.updateOne({ _id: id }, [{ $set: updateQuery }]).exec().catch(() => undefined);
  }
});
```